# MySQL How do I update rows based on existing values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm normalizing an existing database. I currently have two columns in Table1, domain and container, with limited distinct combinations (currently ~30 combinations of these two from ~1000 records). I've built a new Table2 that holds all combinations, with a primary key (container_id) auto-generated when a new record is installed. I've added a container_id column to Table1, and want to fill in the values based on the Table1.container column.

At this point, all of the container names in table 2 are distinct, but that could change in the future, hence the need for a unique number as the PK.

i.e.

```
UPDATE Table1   
SET container_id = (SELECT Table2.container_id
    FROM Table2
    WHERE Table2.container = Table1.container)
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT Table2.container_id
    FROM Table2
    WHERE Table2.container = Table1.container)
```

This query return `error 1242: subquery returns more than one row.`
Am I barking up the totally wrong tree? Table2 should have zero duplicate values.

Comment: There are two subqueries in your UPDATE statement, and only the first one could produce that error. Based on the subquery's condition, I can conclude only one thing: your surmise that "all of the container names in table 2 are distinct" is no longer true.

Answer (score 0):

I should have used a join to update the table1

```
UPDATE Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 USING (container) 
SET Table1.contanier_id = Table2.contanier_id
WHERE Table1.contanier_id IS NULL AND Table2.contanier_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Table2.container is not unique, hence can get repeated. Due to this both sub queries return more than one row.